# How to achieve Runtime polymorphism in java

Tags: java

Consider the below program:

```
class Bike{
   void run(){System.out.println("running");}
 }

class Splender extends Bike{

   void run(){
          System.out.println("running safely with 60km");
   }

   void run2(){
        System.out.println("running2 safely with 60km");
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
     Bike b = new Splender();//upcasting
     b.run2();
   }
 }
```

**My Question:**

```
b.run2();
```

How to access the `run2` method of derived class using base class object?
As of now it is throwing compilation error:

```
242/Splender.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
     b.run2();
      ^
  symbol:   method run2()
  location: variable b of type Bike
1 error
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know about a method called `run2()` on the class `Bike`. You have to provide the compiler a reference to a type with such a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When assigining `Bike b = new Splender();`, you assign the variable `b` a type of `Bike`.
To access methods of `Splender`, you need to cast: `((Splender) b).run2();`

As I saw your comment: implementing an interface results in the same compile "problem" that the compiler does not know about the 'specialized' methods, he will only know the interfaces methdods. But casting will work there too.
The only way to avoid this would be to move `run2()` to the interface which would be a contradiction to your question/use case

Comment: Will it be solved if make `Bike` as `interface` and implement in subclass? (eg: `interface Bike`)

Comment: no problem, just for my curiosity: is this a real use case or just a personal question? ;)

Comment: I'm new to `java` and there is some problem I need to solve based on this input.

Answer (score 6):

To be able to access methods declared in subclasses, one has to downcast to the respective class:

```
((Splender) b).run2();
```

Which of course might result in a runtime error when using an incompatible object.

Comment: Will it be solved if make `Bike` as `interface` and implement in subclass? (eg: `interface Bike`)

Comment: No, only if you also move `run2` up to the `Bike` class/interface.

Answer (score 5):

By casting it again

```
((Splender)b).run2();
```

there is no other way.